# Perl Script Is Hanging With Tomcat Server

Tags: linux, perl, tomcat

I am running a Perl script in which I need to start a tomcat server. After starting the server I need to execute a different linux command.

In the Perl script after starting tomcat it isn't coming out to the next line as tomcat sever is running..

```
system("tomcat.sh run >log.txt");
system("ls");
```

I tried to open the server in different terminal. But control remains there itself.

```
system("xterm", "-hold", "-e", " tomcat.sh run");
```

I tried `exec` in place of `system` but the behaviour is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [**system**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) blocks until the process finishes. I'm not sure on how to deal with such situation, you might fork it, close STDIN before you run external process etc. Instead of system, you might try `IPC::System::Simple`, which handles a lot of platform-specific details for you, or modules like `IPC::Run` or `IPC::Open3`.

Similar to your issue: [Why does my jzip process hang when I call it with Perl's system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024482/why-does-my-jzip-process-hang-when-i-call-it-with-perls-system)

Comment: I used fork() command to control the processes.  Thanks Chankey,

Answer (score 3):

If you use the single string version of system then you can append an `&` to run your command in the background:

```
system("tomcat.sh run >log.txt &");
```

Should do the trick.

I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711520/how-can-i-run-perl-system-commands-in-the-background)

Comment: Thanks Jonhn, But i tried using this '&' earlier, But same problem.. :(

Comment: That's very weird.  I tested it. Are you trying to do it with xterm?

Comment: i am using system("tomcat.sh run >log.txt &");

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/410472/bin-sh-cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off-error-when-running-shellcode).  It might help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, I used fork() command to control the process..